# How to use django-ddp

Tags: django, meteor, ddp

I'm using django as backend. While reading stuff about meteor, i found django-ddp.
I searched a lot, but I didn't get what django-ddp is for. 
I understood that you can use it to connect meteor to your django backend, but what is the use case?

How does the client connect to django and/or meteor? Does meteor have to run on the same server? How are the http requests handled?

Maybe a tiny example would help me to get this.

For me important: Can i use this to combine benefits of django and meteor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django DDP provides a Meteor compatible, realtime, latency compensated backend framework for [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (Python) models.  It can also serve your Meteor frontend code (HTML/JS/CSS/...) allowing you to avoid using Meteor (and node.js) on the server, whilst serving regular Django views at the same time.

Django is a respected web framework with a powerful object relational mapper (ORM), with support for schema migrations included by default.  Django DDP is efficient and secure, using [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) to handle HTTP requests and manage concurrency at the process level, and multiple processes (across multiple hosts) to allow scaling-out to serve many clients simultaneously.  WebSockets are handled using [gevent-websocket](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent-websocket).  Combining these aspects with the realtime, latency compensated benefits of Meteor does indeed give you the advantages of both (unless you *prefer* to run node.js on your backend servers).

If Django DDP is used to serve your Meteor app then the client (browser) will connect to Django DDP automatically.  Otherwise, you can connect your Meteor app to Django DDP and use the Django DDP connection like this:

```js
if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Django = DDP.connect('http://ddp.example.com/');
    Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('myapp.Tasks', {connection: Django});
    Django.subscribe('Tasks', {
        onReady: function(error, result) {
            // Log each matching Task to the browser console in a table
            console.table(Tasks.find().fetch());
        }
    });
}
```

If you're serving your Meteor app from Django DDP then drop the `DDP.connect` line and omit the second parameter to `new Mongo.Collection`.

You might find the [Todos example app](https://github.com/commoncode/django-ddp/tree/develop/dddp/test) a useful place to start.  It includes a full working example of how to write both the Meteor client app and the Django DDP server app.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Django DDP - sorry if parts of my answer sound like marketing guff but I'm just trying to answer the first part of the question.

Comment: Thanks for this big reply. The gevent information was the thing i missed. Offtopic: Is there an easy solution to deploy such a wep project without building up a web server from scratch?

Comment: @FaBay I'm aware of one co-worker deploying django-ddp on Heroku, care to ask another question on how to deploy a django-ddp project so I may answer it?

Comment: May I ask on how to deploy a django-ddp project?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada - can you upvote this answer if it's useful?  And sure, I'd be happy to answer the deployment question if you ask it as another question -- I'd like more rep.  ;-)

Comment: @Tyson, may I ask on how to deploy it or run on a localhost server? I really like the django-ddp project and would like to learn more of it